# How can I print all cards from "List Done" list in Py-trello?

Tags: python, trello

I have written function that returns array with all trello cards:

```
def get_cards_from_board(my_board_1):
    T = []
    lists = my_board_1.list_lists()
    for l in lists:
        cards = l.list_cards()
        for c in cards:
            assert isinstance(c, object)
            T.append(c)
    return T
```

But I want to return/print all trello cards that have been done, another words all trello cards from one list - . How can I do that ?

Comment: How can we tell that a "card" is "done"?

Comment: We replace it to "List Done" list. I need to return all trello cards from one "List Done" list but not from all lists in board. My script returns all cards from all lists and all boards.

Comment: Your code does not contain a "List Done". Is it an item in `lists`? Which?

Comment: is `List Done` some element of `lists`? How do we know if the current list is `List Done`, is some property attached to the list?

Comment: Please make your question more precise and to the point. There is too much intel missing in the question to which the answer you demand

Comment: Yes it is an item in lists. I have tried filtering "List Done" - list_lists("List Done" ) or list_cards("List Done" ) but it doesn't work. https://github.com/sarumont/py-trello/blob/master/trello/board.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the answer by myself:

```
def get_cards_from_board(my_board_1):
T = []
lists = my_board_1.list_lists()
for l in lists:
    if l.name == 'Done':
        cards = l.list_cards()
        for c in cards:
            assert isinstance(c, object)
            T.append(c)
return T
```